# Resampling minute data in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have minute-based OHLCV data like this.

```
                    Date        Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
Timestamp                       
2005-09-07 08:01:00 2005-09-07  1112.75 1113.00 1112.75 1113.00 5
2005-09-07 08:02:00 2005-09-07  1113.00 1113.00 1113.00 1113.00 176
2005-09-07 08:03:00 2005-09-07  1113.00 1113.00 1112.75 1112.75 169
2005-09-07 08:04:00 2005-09-07  1112.75 1112.75 1112.75 1112.75 9
2005-09-07 08:05:00 2005-09-07  1112.75 1112.75 1112.75 1112.75 45
2005-09-07 08:06:00 2005-09-07  1112.75 1113.00 1112.75 1112.75 176
2005-09-07 08:07:00 2005-09-07  1112.75 1113.00 1112.75 1113.00 78
2005-09-07 08:08:00 2005-09-07  1113.00 1113.00 1113.00 1113.00 8
2005-09-07 08:09:00 2005-09-07  1113.00 1113.00 1112.75 1113.00 12
2005-09-07 08:10:00 2005-09-07  1113.00 1113.00 1112.75 1112.75 77
```

I want to resample to any intervals. The below command works for 5 mins.

```
df.resample("5min", label="right", closed="right").sum()

                    Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
Timestamp                   
2005-09-07 08:05:00 5564.25 5564.50 5564.00 5564.25 404
2005-09-07 08:10:00 5564.50 5565.00 5564.00 5564.50 351
2005-09-07 08:15:00 5564.00 5564.25 5563.25 5563.50 1051
```

However, for 7 mins, the first row is 08:03.

```
df.resample("7min", label="right", closed="right").sum()

                    Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
Timestamp                   
2005-09-07 08:03:00 3338.75 3339.00 3338.50 3338.75 350
2005-09-07 08:10:00 7790.00 7790.50 7789.50 7790.00 405
2005-09-07 08:17:00 7789.25 7789.75 7788.25 7789.00 1173
2005-09-07 08:24:00 7789.25 7790.25 7788.75 7789.25 743
```

I want the first row to be 08:07:00, then 08:14:00, ... Do you know how to do this? I tried origin and offset but still can't make it work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide the explicit expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the first row to start at `2005-09-07 08:07:00`, you can supply the Timestamp `2005-09-07 08:00:00` to the `origin` parameter within [`df.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

Let's retrieve this value by applying [`Index.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.min.html) (or simply: `df.index[0]` if the index is in chronological order), and then [`ts.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html) to floor the smallest Timestamp to its hour.

```
origin = df.index.min().floor(freq='H')
# Timestamp('2005-09-07 08:00:00')

df.resample("7min", label="right", closed="right", origin=origin).sum()

                        Open    High     Low    Close  Volume
Timestamp                                                    
2005-09-07 08:07:00  7789.75  7790.5  7789.5  7790.00     658
2005-09-07 08:14:00  3339.00  3339.0  3338.5  3338.75      97
```

---

Incidentally, you might wonder why applying `resample` without `origin` specified started with `2005-09-07 08:03:00`. This is because, by default, it will take the start of the (first) day as its starting point, i.e. `2005-09-07 00:00:00`.

So, in your case, step `"7min"` will make `2005-09-07 08:03:00` the first bin to show up with values (i.e. `pd.Timestamp('2005-09-07 00:00:00') + pd.Timedelta(minutes=7*69)`).

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the `origin` and `offset` parameters of [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df.resample("7min", label="right", closed="right",
            origin="start", offset="6min"
            ).sum()
```

Output:

```
                        Open    High     Low    Close  Volume
Timestamp                                                    
2005-09-07 08:07:00  7789.75  7790.5  7789.5  7790.00     658
2005-09-07 08:14:00  3339.00  3339.0  3338.5  3338.75      97
```